# AngularJS directive name starts with a number, can't get it to work.

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

here is my code:

```
app.directive('3dPlansSlider', function(){
  return {
    controller: 'projectCtrl',
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'views/3dPlansSlider.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

    }
  }
});
```

It is pretty standard in fact, all my directive have exactly this code, but it seems like I'm not able to then import it in my html using the element it created. I'm wondering if there is a way to make it work or it is impossible to get it to work since it starts by a number?

Here is the html:

```
<3d-plans-slider></3d-plans-slider>
```

In the page, it doesn't say any errors, it just prints the <3d-plans-slider> (as if it was basic character) but it does not print the closing tag... I'm about to rename it but I figured out there must be a way to make it work.

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/dafb8a3cd12e7c3247838f536c25eb796331658d/src/ng/compile.js#L2029

Comment: @Daniel_L very nice reference thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you reference your directive, just prepend `-data` like this:

```
<data-3d-plans-slider></data-3d-plans-slider>
```

Keeping your directive defined the same way

```
app.directive('3dPlansSlider', function(){
  return {
    controller: 'projectCtrl',
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: 'views/3dPlansSlider.html',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){

    }
  }
});
```